# SQLSTATE 08001 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: php, sql-server, ssl-certificate, odbc, windows-server

I recently switched from IIS Express to IIS on Windows Server. When doing the migration I had problems recognizing PHP, I did the ODBC installation, etc. However, I got the following error even though I already have an SSL certificate.

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => 08001
             [SQLSTATE] => 08001
             [1] => -2146893019
             [code] => -2146893019
             [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL
Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not
trusted.

             [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL
Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not
trusted.

         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => 08001
             [SQLSTATE] => 08001
             [1] => -2146893019
             [code] => -2146893019
             [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client
unable to establish connection
             [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL
Server]Client unable to establish connection
         )

)
```

I want to believe that the problem is with the settings for the connection.  The database version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

```
<?php
   $serverName = "//serverName\instanceName";
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database", "UID"=>"UID","PWD"=>"PWD");
   $connection = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( !$connection ) {
     die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }

?>
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with the SSL/TLS certificate in IIS, it's complaining about the self-signed certificate on your SQL Server instance. Have you read [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) yet? **BREAKING CHANGE - Default Encrypt to Yes/Mandatory**... which means you either need to turn off connection encryption using `Encrypt=No;` in your connection string, or trust the self-signed certificate with `TrustServerCertificate=Yes;` in your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Adding parameters to the connection info worked

```
Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;
```

Someone suggested **TrustServerCertificate=Yes;** that will not work nor give errors

Comment: In the case of Python, you should use `Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;`